# Why does the sum of probabilities of intersections of events equal this?

Tags: summation

Why is it that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^N P(A_k) = \sum_{j=k}P(A_j A_k)$$

I know the law of total probability but I'm not sure if this applies to that. I'm not told that the sequence of events are disjoint or independent so I'm just wondering how I would get this equality.

Comment: $$A_k \cap A_k = A_k$$

Comment: What is (the scope of) $j$?